# What are some government expenditure reports from the Middle ages?

Tags: government, early-medieval, taxes

I'm curious to see how much money went where in the medieval governments of Europe, but I'm not even sure where to start looking.

Comment: I'm not sure that there was a whole lot of book-keeping done during the early-medieval period. Also Europe is a big place with a lot of different governments, perhaps you might want to narrow the range somewhat.

Comment: @KillingTime Europe is my definite range.

Answer (score 5):

If the British Isles are within your range, the [Pipe Rolls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_rolls) survived in a continuous series from 1155, with some earlier ones also extant. The UK [National Archives](http://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/help-with-your-research/research-guides/medieval-financial-records-pipe-rolls-1130-1300/) has information online about how to access them. The [Pipe Roll Society](http://www.piperollsociety.co.uk/index.htm) is dedicated to publishing them.

Unless you're a Latin scholar, you'll want to access someone else's research into the rolls to get the kind of information you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In a book about Byzantine history I read that there is one recorded imperial budget from the reign of Andronicus II (reigned 1282-1328).